# Time series split with multiple products - python

Tags: python, split, time-series, cross-validation

I have a time series like:

```
index date id value
0     d1   a  10
1     d2   a  15
2     d2   b  20
3     d3   a  18
4     d3   b  19
5     d4   b  21
6     d4   c  25
```

I want to do a time series split, so the splits would be:

```
train_1 = index[0], test_1 = index[1, 2]
train_2 = index[0, 1, 2], test_2 = index[3, 4]
```

and so on...

Is there a simple way so I can implement on a cross-validation, like:

```
for train_idx, test_idx in split_indexes:
    model.fit(X.iloc[train_idx], y_tr.iloc[train_idx])
    ...
```

Comment: What are your constraints? Do the training rows need to come before the test rows? Should each segment be contiguous? Does the training segment always include the first row?

Comment: In each split the training fold is basically the last training + test folds, while the test fold is the next n periods.